# SQL Update trigger comparing NULL with value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers, sql-update

I'm trying to create an Update trigger on a table. The aim is to keep an audit trail of changes made to that table. 
The code is long, so I'll try to simplify it here:

When the update on tbl1 happens:

```
@NewFirstName = FirstName
@NewLastName = LastName
```

From inserted

```
@OldFistName = FirstName
@OldLastName = LastName
```

From Deleted

Now I want to create a string that will tell the user something like this:
ID1 has changed from John to Michael

Here is the code I have

```
if (@OldFistName <> @NewFirstName )          
set @AuditString = @AuditString + ' NewFirstName from ' + cast(@OldFistName as varchar)  + '  to  ' +  cast (@NewFirstName as varchar)  + ','
```

The problem I'm facing is that many field in the database have NULLS. So if for example, FistName is NULL, the code will not work because it is comparing NULL with something, which give me null.

Is there any way around this?

I'm using SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a simple workaround. Just check in your `if` condition whether the variables are null. The code would look like:

```
if @OOldFistName is null
  -- Your code to handle this
else if @NewFirstName is null
  -- Your code to handle this
else if (@OldFistName <> @NewFirstName )
set @AuditString = @AuditString + ' NewFirstName from '
                   + cast(@OldFistName as varchar) + ' to '
                   + cast (@NewFirstName as varchar) + ','
```

Comment: I thought about that but it wont work because I dont want to do anything to all the NULL. I only want the string to form is it is a NULL and the value has changed. I just worked out how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Just worked out how to do this, add AND condition

```
if   (@OldFistName is null AND @NewFirstName IS NOT NULL )
  set @AuditString = @AuditString + ' FistName from ' + 'NULL '  + '  to  ' +  cast (@NewFirstName as varchar)  + ','
  ELSE
  if (@OldFistName <> @NewFirstName )          
  set @AuditString = @AuditString + ' NewFirstName from ' + cast(@OldFistName as varchar)  + '  to  ' +  cast (@NewFirstName as varchar)  + ','
```